# Running headless Firefox or chrome in DigitalOcean

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to run headless Chrome or Firefox in DigitalOcean and have tried alot of solutions but none seem to work.

The code works superb in my local system but in my DigitalOcean server it doesn't.

This is a test i am using to test headless Firefox

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


# print("open virtual display")
with Display():
    print("open Firefox browser")
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.set_window_size(1120, 550)

    url = 'http://arbspiper.com/'
    browser.get(url)

    title = browser.title
    print(title)
    browser.quit()
```

The error i get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "firefox.py", line 9, in <module>
      browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    File "/home/arbspiper_project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
    File "/home/arbspiper_project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    File "/home/arbspiper_project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    File "/home/arbspiper_project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "/home/arbspiper_project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession
```

Mozilla Firefox 64.0
Selenium version (3.141.0)

Comment: What version of geckodriver are you using? You might need to upgrade it. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6590

Comment: i was using v0.18. upgraded it to gekodriver 0.23.0 which is compatible with Mozilla Firefox 64.0 Selenium version (3.141.0). --Manoj you are awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from *Manoj Kengudelu*'s comment.

gekodriver has to be compatible with ther version of firefox you are using.
check out [supported platforms table here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6590)

once you found the gekodriver you would like to use you can download it, make it executable and add it to path.

Thanks again: Manoj Kengudelu